# Can I make relation to Firebase Database and RDBMS(MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use Firebase and sync the data on MySQL.
The purpose of this is I want to use relationships in 
already exists MySQL.

For example, I create a node: `users` on Firebase Database as follows:

```
{
  "<firebase_uid>": {
    "name": "Taro",
    "gender": "man"
  }, ...
 }
```

And this node is copied on MySQL as follows:

```
| column     |  type   |                comment                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| user_id    | varchar | uid what is created on Firebase.       |
| name       | varchar |                                        |
| gender     | varchar |                                        |
```

And I want to create a table: `users_favorites` as follows.

```
| column     |  type   |                comment                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| user_id    | varchar | uid what is created on Firebase.       |
| article_id | int     | article id what is created on my RDBMS.|
```

Does the design have any problems?
Especially, I'm afraid of that I use firebase uid as a primary key on MySQL.

Regards,

Comment: Storing users in the Firebase Database under their `uid` is quite common. But aside from that a lot depends on how you want to access the data. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and viewing [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation! I read and watched these, and I understood that usually make node like `userFavoriteArticles` as denormalizing data on Firebase Database. But I have many data like `articles` on mySQL, and I want to extract the data with user info on Firebase DB at one time. Then, I'm afraid of that Firebase Database size is too bigger if I make many denormalizing nodes. So I came up with this design. Is it bad?

Comment: Both links I gave explain that duplicating data is quite common in NoSQL solutions such as Firebase. IIRC the quote is "data storage is cheap, the user's time is not".

Comment: Hmm...it's words of wisdom. I may be wrong but I interpret that if I want to make relationships between MySQL and Firebase Database, then I have to copy/migrate MySQL data to Firebase Database. Is what I'm saying correct?